# Spring - MyClass$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$87123456 proxy bean has all its @Autowired beans null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, autowired

I have a class `MyClass` :

```
public class MyClass
{
  @Autowired
  private MyClassA myClassA;
}

@Component
public class MyClassA
{
  @Autowired
  private MyClassB myClassB;

  @Transactional
  public void myTransaction()
  {
  }

}

@Component
public class MyClassB
{
}
```

Both MyClassA and `MyClassB` are in a different project(jar).
The problem I am facing is whenever I use `@Autowire` or `@Resource` to create myClassA bean, myClassB of myClassA bean is null. 
Why is myClassB bean null?

Does this mean my spring configuration has some problem?

Comment: Do you declare your classes MyClassA and MyClassB as beans?

Comment: @mael yes, updated question as well.

Comment: How do you know that `myClassB` field is null ? Are you facing a NullPointerExeception ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask: are you sure that MyClassA is in a package that spring will scan?

Comment: @mael had it been the case, wouldn't spring thrown an exception at the time of initializing the bean itself?

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont Exactly I am facing NullPointerException

Comment: Can you show the code how you are accessing myClassA and myClassB beans from code, post a sample test code which fails?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but I had a similar issues in the past when Spring created a proxy for a class before doing the autowiring. This meant that the Spring code that does the autowiring couldn't find any further annotations (such as @Autowired), as the proxy that is autogenerated doesn't have any of those annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the methods that you are calling on the bean that has the proxy wrapper are public. If they have default or protected access then calls to them will not be proxied and will enter an instance of the 'bean' before it was autowired and proxied by Spring.

This can be a difficult bug to find if you don't know how Spring proxying works because there are no warnings to help direct you to the cause.